# Efficient way to integrate Informatica MDM DaaS email validation utility as Cleanse function

Tags: informatica, master-data-management

We have DaaS email validation utility subscription provided from Informatica which we have added as Cleanse function in MDM HUB.

we are trying to bypass the DaaS utility validation if email from source is coming as blank or null. just to avoid unnecessary use of utility as it is chargeable based on number of hits consume.

We used "Is String Empty" function in mapping and navigated to some hardcoded value and only allowed valid email value to be passed in DaaS cleanse function. But we see the MDM Mapping is still consuming the DaaS cleanse function and our hits are always decrementing for Null or Blank email values also.  We are looking for some efficient way to smartly handle this use-case.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Is String Null as as well as Is String Empty function in the cleanse funtion in MDM. The reason because for MDM, empty and null are different .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).